# Stacking layers of permutation: Calculating Monte Carlo p values using other Monte Carlo p values

Tags: statistical-significance, inference, monte-carlo, small-sample, permutation-test

I want to perform One-way analysis with permutation test. In this [link](https://rcompanion.org/rcompanion/d_06a.html), I found some instructions how to proceed in R. In that tutorial, the example data set has equal sample sizes by factor:

[image]

I was wondering to apply similar approach with  unequal sample sizes by factors:

[image]

I believe that in this situation, some sort of control of differences in sampling effort has to be accounted, avoiding run the analysis with unequal samples sizes. Also I'm think is necessary avoid throwing data away and loss information.

To deal with this problems, I wish to use a kind of rarefaction** approach  to accomplish this task, equating the effort by factors without loosing information. To do so, one could apply multiple runs of analysis, as I will try to describe below:

In the unequal example the factor A has only five observations, so, in RUN1 we rarefy all the other factors to only five random selected observations*** too, equating efforts:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Note a pseud.p value**** for RUN1. This value could be calculated with independence_test() function from package coin, using permutation procedures from the [tutorial](https://rcompanion.org/rcompanion/d_06a.html) cited before.
 The next step is repeat the rarefaction of observations from factors B and C, selecting five observations by factor and calculating another pseudo p value, from RUN2 to RUN1000:

[image: ![enter image description here]

In the end, I wish to calculate one mean using all 1000 calculated pseudo p values. Since this procedure is repeated many many times, the information from all observations contributes to the final p value. This unified p value will be used to make inferences.

If this unified p value be significant, I wish also to apply the same rarefaction procedure on a post-hoc test using the headtail function from FSA package. See the [tutorial](https://rcompanion.org/rcompanion/d_06a.html) cited before.

Now the questions:

1-Since both functions (independence_test(),headtail()) already do permutation, is correct to do what I described above? In other words is correct to add another/s "layer/s" of permutation procedures?

2-If question 1 is correct, does someone knows any paper or book that apply identical or similar approach?

** rarefaction is a procedure widely used in biodiversity analysis to deal with distinct numbers of sampling units, individuals or frequencies between factors/treatments.[link](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1046/j.1461-0248.2001.00230.x/full)

*** Note that all five observations values from factor B and C are presented on the original data-set, on which B has ten observations and C has fifteen.

**** p values only for illustration, not actually calculated

Comment: I suspect the tests of location in the coin package aren't bothered by unequal sample sizes among groups.  For example, see [Coin::LocationTests](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/coin/versions/0.4-9/topics/LocationTests), perhaps in particular the `oneway_test` example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a reason why in this case with unequal sample sizes a different permutation approach is required. The null hypothesis is that the distribution of the `Response` is the same no matter whether the `Factor` assumes value A or B or C. Thus, if the assignment of the label A/B/C were random it can also be re-randomized without loss of information. Therefore, to obtain a $p$-value, you simply permute (many times) the observed `Response` on the `Factor` and re-compute the test statistic of your choice.  This is what `independence_test()` does internally. Note that the function `oneway_test()` - as already mentioned in the comments - is a convenience interface exactly for the $k$-sample situation.

Comment: If possible, could you please  give a brief example of oneway_test() for unbalanced datasets with  block structure?

Comment: An example with `independence_test()` for a categorical response (rather than `oneway_test()` with a numeric response) is provided in the main journal paper ("A Lego System for Conditional inference", The American Statistician, 60(3), 257-263. Vignette version: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coin/vignettes/LegoCondInf.pdf). See the section "Contingency Tables: Smoking and Alzheimer’s Disease". The function `oneway_test()` can be used in the same way for a numeric response.